# How to use enter key as separator in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using a tags package in my flutter app and there's a parameter for it for separating the tags and add new tag so I want the enter key or the return key as the `separator` for tags but I'm unable to kind any keyword specified for using enter key in flutter or how I can do it. If anyone knows then please let me know and make sure that it fits the package too cause I am using the package and packages do have restriction. Here's the code

```
ChipTags(
                          list: _myListCustom,
                          separator: "",
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Added Tags",
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                            ),
                          ),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        ),
```

Answer (score -1):

Tags can be separated by pressing Spacebar. It automatically saves previous tag and start new one.

Comment: That's not what I asked I already know this I can put any key like spacebar " " like this or any other key like comma etc but I want enter key. Don't answer wrong

Comment: No, There are no options for enter key, you can separate either from space , comma or something symbolic  as you can see-                                                                                          
                if (value.endsWith(widget.separator ?? " ")) {
                ///check for ' ' and duplicate tags
                if (value != ' ' && !widget.list.contains(value.trim())) {
                  widget.list
                      .add(value.replaceFirst(widget.separator, '').trim());
                }

Comment: I know this stuff thanks anyway

Comment: Then it was not needed to ask this question...welcome anyway.